# How can I filter results using RxSwift, RxRealmDataSources and UISearchController?

Tags: ios, swift, realm, uisearchcontroller, rx-swift

I am using RxSwift with RxRealm and RxRealmDataSources. My realm objects are binded to the table view. I'm trying to find a way to filter it based on query typed into search bar. Has anyone of you done sth like this?

```
class ItemsViewController: UITableViewController {

    let bag = DisposeBag()
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    let search = BehaviorSubject(value: "")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        definesPresentationContext = true
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
        bindTableView()
    }

    func bindTableView() {
        let dataSource = RxTableViewRealmDataSource<Item>(cellIdentifier: "itemCell", cellType: UITableViewCell.self) { cell, ip, item in
            cell.textLabel?.text = item.uuid
        }
        Observable.changeset(from: DataStore.sharedInstance.getObjects(Item.self))
            .bind(to: tableView.rx.realmChanges(dataSource))
            .addDisposableTo(bag)
    }

}

extension ItemsViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {

    public func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        search.onNext(searchController.searchBar.text ?? "")
    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `filter` after `Observable.changeset(from: DataStore.sharedInstance.getObjects(Item.self))`?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is:

```swift
func bindTableView() {
    let dataSource = RxTableViewRealmDataSource<Item>(cellIdentifier: "itemCell", cellType: UITableViewCell.self) { cell, ip, item in
        cell.textLabel?.text = item.uuid
    }
    search.asObservable()
        .map { text in DataStore.sharedInstance.getObjects(Item.self).filter("someProperty == %@", text) }
        .flatMap { results in Observable.changeset(from: results) }
        .bind(to: tableView.rx.realmChanges(dataSource))
        .addDisposableTo(bag)
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work as expected - results are filtered in right way, but table does not show it right. If I print results, everything seems to be fine, but it looks like `.bind(to: tableView.rx.realmChanges(dataSource))` does not work. Any idea what I may be doing wrong ? I'm using the snipped you provided. Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

The problem in https://stackoverflow.com/a/46364131/7694178 might be with multiple bindings. Try this:

```
let changeset = Observable.changeset(from: DataStore.sharedInstance.getObjects(Item.self))
Observable.combineLatest(changeset, search.asObservable()) { changeset, string in
        return (changeset.0.filter("someProperty == %@", string), changeset.1)
    }
    .bind(to: tableView.rx.realmChanges(dataSource))
    .disposed(by: bag)
```